# How to resolve 24.3 iOS Rejection issue (Parental permission)?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, parental-control

We could not submit to Kids category, as we do not comply with:

```
24.3 - Apps in the Kids Category must get parental permission or use a parental gate before allowing the user to link out of the app or engage in commerce
```

Is there an iOS API to resolve this (something like camera permission or such)? Or do we have to implement a custom solution for parental supervision? How did you resolve this rejection issue?

Comment: put you menu/button with "IAP", links to other external sources, etc "under" something like this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=parental

Comment: Weird, I was hoping there is a more "unified" / drop-in / Appleuesque way to do this.

Comment: There are tons of options in Settings/General/Restriction, also there is Guided Access to opt out external stuff. :/ Why they reject for the lack of a custom layer on the top of this at all?

Comment: Check this documentation https://developer.apple.com/app-store/parental-gates/